# How do you stop Node.js from including the dev dependency node modules?

Tags: node.js, webpack, vscode-extensions, esbuild

I'm new to both Node.js development as well as VS Code extension authoring.

I have a working VS Code extension that runs as expected and does exactly what I want. As part of the development, it has a ton of dev dependencies, but only a few runtime dependencies.

Here's the relevant bits of `package.json`:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "get-port": "6.1.2",
        "plist": "3.0.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/glob": "^8.0.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
        "@types/node": "16.x",
        "@types/plist": "3.0.2",
        "@types/vscode": "^1.74.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.2.0",
        "esbuild": "0.16.17",
        "eslint": "^8.28.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.6.0",
        "glob": "^8.0.3",
        "mocha": "^10.1.0",
        "prettier": "2.8.2",
        "typescript": "^4.9.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "esbuild": "npm run esbuild-base -- --sourcemap",
        "esbuild-base": "esbuild ./src/extension.ts --bundle --outfile=out/main.js --external:vscode --format=cjs --platform=node",
        "esbuild-watch": "npm run esbuild-base -- --sourcemap --watch",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
        "package": "vsce package",
        "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
        "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js",
        "test-compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run esbuild-base -- --minify",
        "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./"
    }
}
```

The issue is when I package up the extension with the following command...

```bash
vsce package
```

it's slurping up all the node modules resulting in a vsix file that's over 150mb!!

Following the instructions regarding how to [bundle your extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension), I set up `.vscodeignore` to exclude the `node_modules` folder, like so...

```
node_modules
.vscode/**
.vscode-test/**
src/**
.gitignore
.yarnrc
**/tsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json
**/*.map
**/*.ts
**/*.vsix
Working/**
```

This got my extension down to about 1.5mbs, but half the functionality stopped working.

This left me really scratching my head as I thought `esbuild` was supposed to pull out and bundle/pack in whatever node dependencies were needed at runtime from that folder.

So now I'm back to slurping up the `node_modules` folder which gets my extension working again, but it's back to over 150mb.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong here?  Again, apologies for the noob questions, but this one really has me stumped.